# Trying to dynamically organize JSON object elements into different arrays based on values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, typescript

This is the JSON I'm working with:

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/xx67-kt59.json?$where=camis%20=%2230112340%22

I'd be dynamically making the queries using different data, so it'll possibly change.

What I'm essentially trying to do is to somehow organize the elements within this array into different arrays based on inspection_date.

So for each unique inspection_date value, those respective inspections would be put into its own collection.

1. If I knew the dates beforehand, I could easily iterate through each element and just push into an array.
2. Is there a way to dynamically create the arrays?

My end goal is to be able to display each group of inspections (based on inspection date) using Angular 5 on a webpage. I already have the site up and working and all of the requests being made.

So, I'm trying to eventually get to something like this. But of course, using whatever dates in the response from the request.

**2016-10-03T00:00:00**

List the inspections

**2016-04-30T00:00:00**

List the inspections

**2016-04-12T00:00:00**

List the inspections

Just for reference, here's the code I'm using:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.title = +params['camis']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
      this.q.getInpectionsPerCamis(this.title).subscribe((res) => {
        this.inspectionList = res;
          console.log(res);
      });
      // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.

    });

  }
```

I wish I could give you more info, but at this point, I'm just trying to get started.

Comment: `array.reduce` seems like a good case for this. You would pass it a function that would check if the given `inspection_date` exists in the current object as a key -- if no, add an empty array to that key -- then just use `array.push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this in jQuery just because it was faster for me, but it should translate fairly well to Angular (I just don't want to fiddle with an angular app right now)

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
$(function() {
  let byDateObj = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/xx67-kt59.json?$where=camis%20=%2230112340%22'
  }).then(function(data) {
    //probably do a check to make sure the data is an array, im gonna skip that
    byDateObj = data.reduce(function(cum, cur) {
      if (!cum.hasOwnProperty(cur.inspection_date)) cum[cur.inspection_date] = [];
      //if the cumulative array doesn't have the inspection property already, add it as an empty array
      cum[cur.inspection_date].push(cur);
      //push to inspection_date array.
      return cum;
      //return cumulatie object
    }, byDateObj);
    //start with an empty object by default;
    console.log(byDateObj);
  }, console.error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll have to do some testing, but so far, looks like it worked! I've done some map/reduce in Java, but not JS yet. I'll def have to check it out and practice a bit more! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, let me know if an error pops up with the code that you are uncertain of how to fix.